# Simple and quick way to parse an XML file in iOS7

Tags: ios, xml

I have a simple XML file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
    <timezone>
        <name>UTC-11:00</name>
        <place>
            <value>American Samoa</value>
            <value>Samoa</value>
        </place>
    </timezone>
    <timezone>
        <name>UTC-10:00</name>
        <place>
            <value>Honolulu</value>
            <value>Tahiti</value>
        </place>
    </timezone>
</catalog>
```

What is the canonical/standard way to parse this in iOS? I want to save "names" and "places" for each name.

Comment: You can use `NSXMLParser` http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-rss-reader-tutorial/

Comment: https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary - You could use something built on top of the framework parser for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSXMLParser is already built in.  You should look at this article for a more thorough comparison.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-choose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

It is `NSXMLParser`. [Official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsxmlparser_class/reference/reference.html)

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: @Morpheus you can't gain reputation for a comment :)

Comment: @Morpheus why should it be a comment, it answers the question

Comment: He just provided a link, not an answer, and SO is not meant only for repo